# bank reconciliation

Tags: php

I am working on a bank  reconciliation project.

I imported two excel files into tables in a database as I'm using  `mysql.table-1` and `table-2`.

I want to compare the values in both tables and the mismatched values in one table should be added in another table so that values are balanced and print out the mismatches in the respective tables.

Can any one help to do this with PHP  ?

Comment: You know the process where's the problem?

Comment: i need some  php codes.i do not know to do with codes

Comment: How far are you able to get? Can you connect to a database?

Comment: No one will write the code in place of you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this in SQL directly in the database?

Comment: You don't need PHP to compare rows in a database. That's the database's job.

Answer (score 1):

These functions should do what you need

[Connect to a database](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). If you don't have PDO and can't get it use [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Since you don't have user input you can use [PDO::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to retrieve the records.

`==` or `===` will compare results from each table.

To insert use [PDO::exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) or mysql_query.

I think that that should be enough to start you off.